# FPDF Page Not Loading Completely On Internet Server But Working Properly On Local Server

Tags: php, fpdf

this is the code

```
    <?php      
require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');     
$pdf = new FPDF('P','in',"LEGAL");     

include_once "../__accinfo.php";     
$link_id=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpassword) or die("Unable To Connect To Server");     

include_once "dbinfo.inc";     
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to Connect To Database");     

$starting=$_POST['rno_start'];     
$ending=$_POST['rno_end'];     
$lmargin=0.5;     
$rmargin=7.5;     

$qry="select * from $dbname where `group`='$_POST[grp]' and inst_code=$_SESSION[INST_CODE] and not isnull(finalized) and serialno>=$starting and serialno<=$ending ORDER BY serialno ASC";     

$result=mysql_query($qry, $link_id);     
$grup="PRE-MEDICAL GROUP";     

$countofrecords=9;     
$title=1.0;     
$cnt=0; $ln[0]=1.5;     
while($cnt<10) {$cnt++;     
    $ln[$cnt]=$ln[$cnt-1]+1.1;     
}     
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))     
{     
    $countofrecords=$countofrecords+1;     
    if($countofrecords==10) {     
        $countofrecords=0;     

        $pdf->AddPage();     

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);       
        $txt="BOARD OF INTERMEDIATE AND SECONDARY EDUCATION MULTAN";                     
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,$txt,0,1,'C');                    $pdf->ln(0.2);     
        $txt="REGISTRATION INTERMEDIATE (11th) 2013-15     $grup";                   
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,$txt,0,1,'C');                         $pdf->ln(0.3);     
        $txt="($_SESSION[INST_CODE]) $_SESSION[INST_NAME]";                  
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,$txt,0,1,'C');     

        $pdf->rect($lmargin,1.0,$rmargin,11.5);                  //the main rectangle box     
        $cnt=-1;     
        while($cnt<9) {$cnt++;     
            $pdf->Line($lmargin,$ln[$cnt],$rmargin+.5,$ln[$cnt]);               
        }     
        $col1=$lmargin+.5;  $col2=$col1+0.8;    $col3=$col2+2.5;     
        $col4=$col3+0.8;    $col5=$col4+0.7;    $col6=$col5+1.3;     
        $pdf->Line($col1,$title,$col1,$ln[10]);     
        $pdf->Line($col2,$title,$col2,$ln[10]);     
        $pdf->Line($col3,$title,$col3,$ln[10]);     
        $pdf->Line($col4,$title,$col4,$ln[10]);     
        $pdf->Line($col5,$title,$col5,$ln[10]);     
        $pdf->Line($col6,$title,$col6,$ln[10]);     

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',10);       
        $pdf->Text($lmargin+.02,$title+.2,"College");     
        $pdf->Text($lmargin+.02,$title+.4,"  RNO");     
        $pdf->Text($col1+.1,$title+.2,"Date Of");       //$pdf->Text(3,3,"TEXT TO DISPLAY");     
        $pdf->Text($col1+.1,$title+.4,"Admission");     
        $pdf->Text($col2+.5,$title+.2,"Name / Father");     
        $pdf->Text($col3+.1,$title+.15,"SSC RNO");     
        $pdf->Text($col3+.1,$title+.30,"SESSION");     
        $pdf->Text($col3+.1,$title+.45,"BOARD");     
        $pdf->Text($col4+.1,$title+.2,"Subjects");     
        $pdf->Text($col5+.1,$title+.2,"B-Form / F-CNIC");     
        $pdf->Text($col5+.1,$title+.4,"/ Contact");     
        $pdf->Text($col6+.15,$title+.2,"Picture");     
    }
        list($y,$m, $d) = split('[/.-]', $data["DOA"]);                      
        $doa=$d."/".$m."/".$y;     

        $imgpath="studentpics/P$data[INST_CODE]$data[CRNO].jpg";     
        if(file_exists($imgpath))     
            $pdf->Image($imgpath,7.15,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.1,.75,.85);     


        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',11);       
        $pdf->Text($col1+.05,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.2,$doa);     

        $pdf->Text($col3+.05,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.25,$data["MRNO"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col3+.02,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.5,$data["MSESSION"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col3+.05,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.75,$data["MBISE"]);     

        $pdf->Text($col5+.05,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.2,$data["CNIC"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col5+.05,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.5,$data["FCNIC"]);     
        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',8);        
        $pdf->Text($col5+.05,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.75,$data["CONTACT"]);     
        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',11);       
        $pdf->Text($lmargin+.15,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.3,$data["SERIALNO"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col2+.07,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.2,$data["NAME"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col2+.07,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.5,$data["FATHER"]);     

        $pdf->Text($col4+.02,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.2,$data["APPEAR4"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col4+.02,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.4,$data["APPEAR5"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col4+.02,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.6,$data["APPEAR6"]);     
        $pdf->Text($col4+.02,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.8,$data["APPEAR7"]);     
        if($data["APPEAR3"]!="IE")     
            $pdf->Text($col4+.15,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.8,$data["APPEAR3"]);     

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',10);       
        if($data["OREGNO"]!="")     
            $pdf->Text($col2+.1,$ln[$countofrecords]+0.75,"Prev. Reg# ".$data["OREGNO"]);     

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',8);        
        $pdf->Text($col1+.05,$ln[$countofrecords]+1,"Address: ".$data["ADDRESS"]);     
}      
$pdf->Text($lmargin+.5,13,"Signature _____________________");     
$pdf->Text($rmargin-2,13,"Stamp _____________________");     
$pg=$pdf->pageNo();     
$pdf->Text($lmargin+3.1,13,"Page: $pg");     

$filename="reg2013.pdf";     
$pdf->Output($filename,'I');     
     ?>
```

but the page not loads. 
keep one thing in mind. it works properly on my local server and generates output properly. but when i upload the script on internet server, it don't show any output.

Answer (score 0):

The program has *at least* three external dependencies:

- `../fpdf/fpdf.php`
- `../__accinfo.php`
- `dbinfo.inc`

and they are all in different directories.  Are you sure the two machines have all of those matching?  And then everything those include, etc.?

---

More:

It seems peculiar that these lines are ordered as they are:

```
$link_id=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpassword) ...
include_once "dbinfo.inc";
```

Where are the `$db`* variables defined?  (Hopefully in `../__accinfo.php`.)

Comment: @adeeliqbal:  I have amended my answer with another possible issue.

Comment: yes these variables are in __accinfo.php. still my issue is unresolved. my local computer is running wamp (windows). however my internet server is on linux

Answer (score 0):

check your dbhost, dbusername and dbpassword if it correspond to your internet server

common mistake is the failure to **update your data from local server data to internet server data**

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpassword)
```